# How do I make street address not a required field?

Tags: civimember

When creating a contributions page for member dues, street address, city, country are all required fields. I do not want them to be. How can I make them not-required fields?

Comment: Are you talking billing address?

Comment: Shane - first, welcome to Civi SE!  Secondly, would you be able to share a bit about why you don't want to make these fields required?  I can think of at least three reasons why you would want to require those fields: first, the more data you have about your constituents, the more effectively you can interact with them.  Second, using more than email makes duplicate matching more robust. Third, your payment processor may need more info for address verification (so you minimize the risk of card tumbling or similar problems).

Comment: Yes, in the Billing Name and Address section. I only really want name, email & post code to be required fields.

Comment: Thanks Lesley. Its really a client request - its for a sensitive issue so divulging all of those details may deter people from using the form. I understand these other items you've outlined. At the very least i'd like to make street address not required.

Comment: Thanks Peter. What you've described isn't quite right. The profiles you've described come before or after the details i'm describing. If i create a contribution page without any profiles, the billing name and address section appears automatically and i don't know where to manage these fields.

Comment: Thanks again Peter. I had seen that thread through a google search. I was hopeful I could add 'street_address' to the $requiredBillingFields variable in the file Jon G referred to but that didn't change anything. The list referenced does mirror what i see in the form and i'm unable to find a similar list in the rest of the code.

Answer (score 1):

First, find which profile is being used in your contribution page by going to Contributions/Manage Contribution Pages/Choose relevant Page and select Configure over on right hand side of screen/Include Profiles.  This page will show which Profile is being used.

Second go to Administer/Customize date and Screens/Profiles.  Find the relevant Profile title and select Fields on the right hand side. This page shows all the fields in use and whether they are required or not. In each field, hover over Yes or No and change them as you wish.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for giving a bit more explanation of your problem.  I found this earlier and similar question that was answered.  The answer by Jon G may go some way to helping with this.[link](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/24821/how-can-i-remove-the-billing-name-and-address-section-from-the-donation-form)

Comment: note Shane made some comments as an Answer, i tried to add them as comments on this Answer but they are on the OP